# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str python

Tags: python

почему вылазит ошибка (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str)
суть кода в том что если в строке есть рядом стоящие два элемента 'R' и 'L' то их нужно поменять местами и вывести получившийся список, а еще нужно подсчитать количество замен, вот что я попытался сделать:

```
s = str(input())
lol = list(s)
c = 0
for i in lol:
    if lol[i] =='R' and lol[i+1]=='L':
        c+=1
        lol[i],lol[i+1]=lol[i+1],lol[i]
print(lol)
```

на выходе ошибка TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str что не так???

Comment: `str(input())` - тут str не нужно т.к. `input` уже выдаёт в формате строки.  `for i in lol:` эту строку нужно заменить на  `for i in range(len(lol) - 1):`

Comment: спасибо помогло

Answer (score 3):

```py
for i in lol:
```

Перебирает элементы списка `lol`, то есть буквы введённые в переменную `c`.

Например, если мы введём в переменную `c` фразу 'Hello World'
то в списке `lol` будут символы из переменной `c`:

```py
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

И `i` будет принимать значение каждого элемента списка `lol`.

В первой итерации `for`, `i` будет равна `H`, во вторую `e` и так далее.

Поэтому при попытке указать `i` как индекс, возникает `TypeError`.

Исправить это можно двумя способами:

```py
s = str(input())
lol = list(s)
c = 0

for i in lol[:-1]: # Перебор всех элементов кроме последнего, иначе в конце поймаем out of range

    num_elem = lol.index(i) # Определение индекса первого элемента с значение i
    
    if lol[num_elem] == 'R' and lol[num_elem + 1] == 'L':
        c+=1
        lol[num_elem], lol[num_elem+1] = lol[num_elem+1], lol[num_elem]

        
print(lol)
```

Этот вариант в исполнении выше не универсален потому что метод `.index()` определяет индекс первого элемента со значением переданным в скобках.

То есть, если в списке будет два одинаковых элемента, индекс в обоих случаях выдаст номер первого. Это конечно можно решить если добавить дубликат `c` и удалять из него элементы, индексы которых мы уже узнали, но легче воспользоваться вторым вариантом:

```py
s = str(input())
lol = list(s)
c = 0

for i in range(len(lol)-1): # Кол-во итераций равно длине lol, но меньше на 1 чтобы в конце не поймать out of range
    
    if lol[i] == 'R' and lol[i+1] == 'L':
        c += 1
        lol[i],lol[i+1] = lol[i+1],lol[i]

        
print(lol)
```

В этом варианте `i` принимает не значения элементов, а их индексы.

Но если задача не в построении алгоритма, а в результате, то проще было бы написать так:

```py
s = input()
c = s.count('RL') # определяем кол-во RL в строке c
lol = list(s.replace('RL', 'LR')) # создаём список из строки s в которой заменили все 'RL' на 'LR'
print(lol)
```